# How to get data from inputs and put them in an array using jQuery?

Tags: c#, jquery, html, arrays, model-view-controller

I generate a 9X9 (row = 9; col = 9) table using 'for' loops (it has 81 cells).

I also have an array of integers Model.grid[9, 9], 45 random elements of which are 0's, the rest are single digits from 1 to 9.

Then I fill the table's cells, as it follows: if the matching grid[,] element is '0', then I put an inputbox in the current cell; if the matching grid[,] element is different than '0' (a digit from 1 to 9), then I fill the cell with that matching grid[,] element.

So the code looks smth like this:

1) Visualizing table:

```
@model Generator.GeneratorClass

@helper drawCells(int row)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < Model.cols; i++)
   {
      if(Model.grid[row, i] == 0)
      {
         <td>
            <input type="text" maxlength="1"/>
         </td>
      }
      else
      {
         <td>
            @Model.grid[row, i].ToString()
         </td>
      }
   }
}

@helper drawRows()
{
   for (int i = 0; i < Model.rows; i++)
   {
      <tr>@drawCells(i)</tr>
   }
}
```

2) HTML:

```
<div id="puzzle">
   <table border="1" id="puzzle-table">
      @drawRows()
   </table>
</div>
<button onclick="check()">
   Check
</button>
```

Till this point everything works fine. The user should eventually fill in the 45 empty table's cells. Then I want after the user has clicked the 'Check' button bellow the table, the check() function to create a new array fields[] and fill it with the values from the input boxes. I use this script, but it doesn't work.

3) Script (doesn't work):

```
function check() {
   var fields = [];
   $('#puzzle-table input').each(function (i) {
      fileds.push(i);
   });
```

How can I get the values from the input boxes and put them in the array fields[] using jQuery?

Comment: There is a spelling mistake on "fields" you have put "fileds.push(i)" in the code sample. Have you checked in the console if $("#puzzle-table input").length is equal to 45?

Comment: `doesn't work` is not a proper problem description. Code shown would throw errors, so you should include errors also in question. If you want value use `val()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function check() {
               var fields = [];
               $('#puzzle-table input').each(function () {
                  fileds.push( $(this).val() );
               });
            }
        </script>
```